# Surjections and equivalence relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, functions, equivalence-relations

> (a)  Let $f: A \to B$ be a surjective function.  We define $a_1 \sim a_2$ if $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$.  Prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

- **Reflexivity:** This comes for free.  If $a_1 \sim a_1$, then $f(a_1)=f(a_1)$.
- **Symmetry:**  Suppose $a \sim b$.  Then $f(a)=f(b)$.  But that is the same as saying $f(b)=f(a)$.  Thus $b \sim a$.
- **Transitivity:**  Suppose $a \sim b$ and $b \sim c$. Then $f(a)=f(b)$ and $f(b)=f(c)$.  Then $f(a)=f(c)$.  Thus $a \sim c$.

> (b)  Suppose $A$ is a set and $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $A$.  Find a set $B$ and a function $f\colon A \to B$ such that $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$ exactly when $a_1\sim a_2$.

This one I'm not sure how to even start.  It does seem like I am trying to prove the converse to part (a), but I am not sure.

Comment: Your free reflexivity isn't quite right. In fact, it's kind of backwards. Can you see why?

Comment: I truncated the proof a lot for that one.  My thinking is that If $a \sim a$, then $f(a)=f(a)$.  But function equality is already reflexive, so it follows that $\sim$ is reflexive.

Comment: EugeneTooms, you've just committed the fallacy of [affirming the consequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent).

Comment: Oh God.  How do I undo this?  I also have problems with reflexivity since it always seems to just come for free.

Comment: This time, it's easy. All you have to do is use the other side of the double implication instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $B = \{[a] : a \in A\}$, where $[a]$ is the equivalence class of $a$. More particularly,

$$[a] = \{x \in A : x \sim a\}$$

Now try defining $f(a) = [a]$.

---

To prove that $f$ has the desired properties, suppose that $a_1 \sim a_2$; then by definition of an equivalence class, $a_1$ and $a_2$ lie in the same equivalence class; that is, $[a_1] = [a_2]$. Hence,

$$f(a_1) = [a_1] = [a_2] = f(a_2)$$

as desired. Now on the other hand, suppose that $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$. Then $[a_1] = [a_2]$, and in particular, $a_1 \in [a_2]$; hence, $a_1 \sim a_2$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Do you mean this: $f(a)=\{x \in A : x \sim a\}$?

Comment: @EugeneTooms Yes, exactly.

Comment: It seems like that definition is just saying that for each $x \in [a]$ there is an $a \in A$ such that $f(a)=x$.  Maybe I just jumped the gun...

Comment: @EugeneTooms Not quite. The desired function just needs to give the same output for every element of the same equivalence class.

Comment: @EugeneTooms I've included the proof that $f$ has the desired properties in my answer.

Comment: So the function is just a function that maps an element into its equivalence class?

Comment: @EugeneTooms Yes, exactly.

Comment: I think the a in your definition of equivalence class should be capitalized.