# How to prove a relation is reflexive and transitive.

Tags: functions, relations

In a question paper (I downloaded from internet) there was a question,

> Let $f\colon A\to B$ be a function. Define $$R := \bigl\{\left(a,b\right) \mid \text{$a,b \in A$ and $f(a)=f(b)$}\bigr\}.$$ Show that $R$ is reflexive and transitive.

How can I solve this problem? Please help me.

Comment: The proof is just a matter of checking that $R$ satisfies the definitions of reflexivity and transitivity. Both are completely straightforward. What do you have to check in order to show that $R$ is reflexive? If you can answer that question, you should be able to show that $R$ is reflexive. If not, you need to look at the definition of reflexivity.

Comment: Do you know the definitions? To solve this question you just need to use the definitions.

Comment: Dkal, Can you explain ?

Comment: lakmal, do you know the definition of a transitive relation? Of a reflexive relation?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476987/surjections-and-equivalence-relations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Huge hint:

Reflexive: For each $a\in A$, $f\left(a\right)=f\left(a\right)$ and hence $\left(a,a\right)$ is in $R$.

Transitive: Suppose $\left(a,b\right),\left(b,c\right)\in R$. Then $f\left(a\right)=f\left(b\right)$ and $f\left(b\right)=f\left(c\right)$ so that $f\left(a\right)=f\left(c\right)$ and hence ***_*_**.

Comment: More than a hint this actually is the answer without the required comments. The definition of the relation solves the question before it was even asked.

Comment: Don't be, as I see it those hints do help students who are new to a certain material get some self confidence in it. I personally +1'ed it.