# Proving that a relation is an equivalence relation

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

I am having difficulties proving the relation IS an equivalence relation.

Let $f: X\longrightarrow Y$ be a function from a set $X$ onto a set $Y$. Let $R$ be  the subset of 
$X \times X$ consisting of those pairs $(x, x')$such that $f(x)= f(x')$. Prove that $R $ is an  equivalence relation.

Let $ \pi: X\longrightarrow X/R$ be a projection. Verify that, if $ \alpha \in X/R$ is an equivalence class, to define $F(\alpha) = F(a)$, whenever $\alpha = \pi (a)$, establishes a well-defined function $F: X/R \longrightarrow Y$ which is one-to-one and onto.

Comment: It is customary to make some attempt at solving and to communicate the problems you encountered...

Comment: For the first part see, for example, [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701376/show-that-the-relation-in-set-of-real-number-is-an-equivalence/702747#702747). This question seems to be related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476987/surjections-and-equivalence-relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the definition of what an equivalence relation is. For instance, $R$ must be shown to be reflexive, meaning that $xRx$ must hold for all $x\in X$. Indeed, given $x\in X$ we have that $f(x)=f(x)$, which by definition means that $xRx$. Now look at the rest of the definition of equivalence relation and verify.

Comment: well, I already did one third of that for you, but "yes!!!!!!!!!".

Comment: You sound like a commercial for content providers back from 12 years ago. :P